# UITableViewCell indentation centering imageView?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uiimageview

Does anyone know of any reason why indentation of a `UITableViewCell` would center the cell's `UIImageView` horizontally? In theory (and judging by the screenshots and apps I've seen in the past), the imageView should always align to the right, keeping a consistent space to the two labels. In my case (screenshot below), it doesn't. This is a default `UITableViewCell` with the `UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle`style. Any clues? I've been looking at this for quite a while and can't seem to figure it out.

**Update:** apparently `UITableViewCellStyleDefault` doesn't have this issue - imageView's are right-aligned with the (single) label. Why there is a difference between the two styles is beyond me.

[image: UITableViewCell]

(green/blue areas added to illustrate the issue)

Comment: Is this cell is created in IB?

Comment: Hi Geoff, no, it's a standard cell. I just noticed that `UITableViewCellStyleDefault` doesn't have this issue whereas `UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle` does. The inconsistency is driving me mad.

Comment: I don't know the exact answer to the question but I have to agree with Geoff - I always create my custom table view cells in interface builder just to avoid annoying things like this :)

Comment: +1 for doing it yourself. Existing cell classes will limit you once you want to take them further than what they are allowed to be. Luckily, it's fairly easy to get good results with little code, if you just implement it by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

How UITableViewCell draws its contentView is not how you would normally draw subviews in an UIView. It does not modify `frame` property of imageView, textLabel and detailLabel. I guess it gets those views graphic references and dealing with custom drawing.

Which means, there is no control. Unfortunately I also have to say you need some customizations. But it would be enough just to have a custom content view, not to subclass the whole table view cell class.

Comment: Does this mean you cannot modify the frame of UITableViewCell components? Is this documented somewhere or is this just from experience? Thanks!

Comment: I believe you can modify the frame of UITableViewCell. What I meant was that frame properties of its subviews does not decide how they are located in a table cell.